# Signal conversion

Tags: level-shifting

How can I convert a 0 to 15V or 0 to 12V square wave signal to 0 to 3V3 signal which should be fed to a icrocontroller or a FPGA?

Can this circuit can used or not?

Please suggest a circuit for the above application.

[image]

Comment: Do you need 2-quadrant low-impedance drive? Or just one quadrant? In any case, you could just use a Schottky diode to the +3.3 V rail and a resistor.

Comment: This is a great way to do it. It will invert the signal, though. When the transducer is HIGH, the MCU will be LOW.

Answer (score 0):

a simple resistive voltage divider will do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's one way to do it. Depending on the output impedance and the output stage of the transducer you could want to add a base shunt do ground. Keep in mind that if the wire is disconnected the gate floats and you'll be in trouble.

A BJT could be a more robust solution (the base is way sturdier than a gate), otherwise you probably need ESD protection and filtering.

As KFE said, an optocoupler would be the definitive solution from the safety standpoint. Also it's the only practical way if the ground is not shared or noisy (how far the transducer is?). Be careful on the switching speed, your signal could be to fast for the coupler.

A simple divider could be useful if the transducer is really near (like, on board) or if you are really sure there will not be damaging events on that line.

If you have many such inputs the ULN2003A is obscenely cheap and gives you 7 switching BJTs.

SLAA148 application note from TI has many suggestions, it's biased toward low power and 5V interfacing but if you redo the math the topologies are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I done this with the help of a voltage divider.  Thanks everyone for giving answer